# How can I get onPress to fire on a React Native Text element inside a TextInput?

Tags: react-native

I have multiple Text elements as children of a TextInput for the purpose of styling. I would like the user to tap on them to activate a modal (unique to that Text element), however I'm unable to get the onPress event to work. Here is a simplified example:

```
<TextInput>
  <Text onPress={() => console.log(1)}>touch me</Text>
</TextInput>
```

"touch me" is editable as you'd expect inside a TextInput, but onPress doesn't fire when it is tapped.

Is there a way I can make this setup work as I intend?

Comment: So you mean when you click on the Text elements coonsole.log doesnt print 1?

Comment: @Sakshi That's correct

Answer (score 0):

You can to wrap it inside a [TouchableOpacity](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity):

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState('Press me');

return <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert("Hello world")}>
  <TextInput
    value={value}
  />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry, I should have been more clear, but I want each Text element's modal to be unique to that particular element. If there is a way to reference the specific child element that was touched then it could work.